# How do I get read_stream permissions from facebook

Tags: facebook

I am attempting to get read_stream using the MS Facebook Tookkit (http://facebooktoolkit.codeplex.com/) in an FBML canvas app  and it issues a request for permissions by redirecting the user to http://www.facebook.com/connect/prompt_permissions.php

the error I get is 
API Error Code: 100
API Error Description: Invalid parameter
Error Message: When enabling the profile selector, an app may not request permissions that do not apply to all profiles in the selector. Note: You are seeing this message because you are a developer of this application. For regular users, inapplicable permissions are silently ignored.

please note, my code has not changed, this worked 5+ months ago.  It does work if the app is set to IFRAME.

any suggestion is greatly appreciated as I am on a tight deadline

Comment: If you are starting a new project, I would suggest you take a look at my SDK at http://facebooksdk.codeplex.com. The Facebook Toolkit has lagged behind in recent months in supporting the new authentication system and apis. We currently use the Facebook .Net SDK in many large scale Facebook apps and are migrating many of our old apps to this new SDK from the Facebook Toolkit.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like it doesn't like profile selector. If you don't need it then maybe there is a way to disable it in your SDK? When it redirects you to that permissions page there must be `enable_profile_selector=1` parameter. Try setting it to 0 and see what happens.

Comment: When i remove the enable_profile_selector and the selected_profiles parameters, it does work, however, it does not display in the standard dialog.  Instead it displays full screen.